# How do I configure AutoHotKey to use mouse for shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, script, mouse, autohotkey

I am trying to create a script that will change desktops based on the following:
When I hold down the right mouse button (i.e right click) and then use the scroll wheel.
Scrolling up should go to left desktop and scrolling right should go to right desktop, all while the right mouse button is held down.
I have tried assigning this to the keyboard Ctrl+Win+Arrow-key but the script just holds down all buttons and keys and I have to restart the computer.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I want to create a scenario whereby i can just hold thr right click mouse button and use the mouse scrollwheel to move between desktops in windows 10. Just like how you move using “ctrl+win+left or right”. I hope you understand now.

Comment: related- autohotkey mouse scroll  https://superuser.com/questions/1715251/a-discord-server-vanished-after-i-tried-to-scroll-through-discord-servers-and-it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
~RButton & WheelUp::    ; next desktop
    Send, ^#{Right}     ; Ctrl+Win+Right
    ToolTip, next desktop
    SetTimer, Remove_ToolTip, 50
return

~RButton & WheelDown::  ; previous desktop
    Send, ^#{Left}      ; Ctrl+Win+Left
    ToolTip, previous desktop
    SetTimer, Remove_ToolTip, 50
return

Remove_ToolTip:
    KeyWait, RButton      ; wait for the RButton to be relased
    SetTimer, Remove_ToolTip, off
    ToolTip               ; remove the ToolTip
    SendInput, {Esc}      ; close the context menu
return
```

Replace `WheelUp` by `WheelRight` and `WheelDown` by `WheelLeft` in the code if you want to use WheelRight/WheelLeft.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the `~` prefix to your hotkey.  Note, however, that the mouse keys specifically seem to have inconsistent behavior similar to the nature that you're encountering.  I've run into the same issue myself and have asked in the AHK Discord but to no avail.  Regarding the "stuck in firing" behavior, note that you can simply reload the script to release the keys that are stuck, or depending on which modifier key it is simply invoking it again manually can also release the key (FYI, you can use keyboard input <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to select the script's tray icon).  While normally buggy behavior of this nature can be circumvented by explicitly defining up/down key states, I have noted that the mouse keys are once again particularly susceptible to this type of behavior irregardless.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Greatly appreciated.