# a discord server vanished after I tried to scroll through discord servers and it's only available through ctrl-k now

Tags: discord

a discord server vanished after I tried to scroll through discord servers and it's only available through ctrl-k now

And besides that, now the button at the top of the server list, that I would click to see my messages, has gone

[image]

That ^^ has gone

What happened was I was strugglign to scroll through the discord servers and I saw buttons that said "new" on the top and bottom and I was finding they scrolled through the server list,  but then that button I mentioned vanished

[image]

Also, one of the servers that I recently joined, vanished from the list too, but I see it if I do ctrl-k and type the name of it

[image]

That first one listed in the ctrl-k used to appear in my server list it was there 10 minutes ago but has vanished once I started clicking the "new" buttons to try to scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll either with a mouse's scroll wheel, or, if on a laptop with a touchpad, then holding two fingers together on the side of the touchpad and simultaneously moving those two fingers up and down.

(both those ways would work in a notepad window too, so you can test it in a notepad window and if you have scrolling then try scrolling through the discord servers)

**update**

I recently found two fingers on the side of the touchpad not working. Currently i am on HP Probook, but I have found a good way to show how to do it.

This works for Windows 7 but should work for later versions of windows too.

Go to Control Panel...Mouse  (or click start/orb, then type 'mouse' and click mouse).

[image]

Then click device settings

[image]

I suppose you could try each of these two items but I find clicking the first one then clicking settings, shows this screen.

And it has an animation of somebody scrolling with their fingers on this touchpad

To scroll up and down he is going from here, then he is moving his fingers down.

[image]

Basically starting from the centre in terms of the x axis, and the top in terms of the y axis. And moving his fingers down.

And he'd go the the other way to scroll up. So from the centre in terms of the x axis, and the bottom in terms of the y axis, and moving his two fingers up.

I find this works.. Not having my fingers on the side and going up and down. Though some touchpads might require it done on the sides.

But the great thing about this is it shows an animation for how to do it on your touchpad.

**Update2**

Another option is
Use autohotkey to make some shortcuts e.g. ctrl-pageup, and ctrl-pagedown, act as scroll up/down.

so I made nn autohotkey file with this code in it.

C:....\mydatafiles....\ahk>type mousewheel.ahk

```
^PgUp::
Send, {wheelup 3}
return
^PgDn::
Send {wheeldown 3}
return

; might want to say   keywait, ctrl just after the ^PgUp::  and just after the ^PgDn::
```

And from my main ahk file(that loads with windows), I have a line `#include %A_ScriptDir%\mousewheel.ahk`